# Build NPM package which serves html elements to embed

Tags: node.js, npm-package

I want to build an npm package that mainly supports browser-based packages. I know creating methods type of npm package is a bit easy to make it. Already I have files index.html(plain HTML elements), index.css, and index.js. Now how can I generate these files into the npm package which serves to embed HTML to the frontend project?